# How to get match last property of object for mongodb collection document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to match last property of object under mongodb collection. For example, two records under my collection are listed below.

```
{
    "_id" : "5:/content/mac/authujul281469689982632/notifications/node",
    "jcr:primaryType" : {
            "r158b588cae9-0-2" : "\"nam:nt:unstructured\"",
            "r158b588d4ed-0-2" : null,
            "r158b58cde26-0-2" : "\"nam:nt:unstructured\""
    },
    ":childOrder" : {
            "r158b588cae9-0-2" : "\"[0]:Name\"",
            "r158b588d4ed-0-2" : null,
            "r158b58cde26-0-2" : "\"[0]:Name\""
    },
    "_deleted" : {
            "r158b588cae9-0-2" : "false",
            "r158b588d4ed-0-2" : "true",
            "r158b58cde26-0-2" : "false"
    },
    "_commitRoot" : {
            "r158b588cae9-0-2" : "4",
            "r158b588d4ed-0-2" : "4",
            "r158b58cde26-0-2" : "4"
    },
    "_modified" : NumberLong(1480514655),
    "_modCount" : NumberLong(3),
    "_deletedOnce" : true
```

}

```
{
    "_id" : "5:/content/mac/authujul281469689982632/notifications/node123",
    "_deleted" : {
            "r158b586fd5d-0-2" : "false",
            "r158b587c23e-0-2" : "true"
    },
    "_commitRoot" : {
            "r158b586fd5d-0-2" : "4",
            "r158b587c23e-0-2" : "4"
    },
    "jcr:primaryType" : {
            "r158b586fd5d-0-2" : "\"nam:nt:unstructured\"",
            "r158b587c23e-0-2" : null
    },
    ":childOrder" : {
            "r158b586fd5d-0-2" : "\"[0]:Name\"",
            "r158b587c23e-0-2" : null
    },
    "_modified" : NumberLong(1480514320),
    "_modCount" : NumberLong(2),
    "_deletedOnce" : true
```

}

I want all records in which last property under "_deleted" is false. That means from above two records, first record will be returned. How to write mongodb query for the same.

Comment: is this data model changeable? based on what you're trying to do, an array would be a better choice of data structure for the _deleted field.

Comment: No. I can not change the data model. I am not storing data, it's being handled by someone else and that core part, which I cannot change.